# Finding a new Handwritten dataset for commercial usage

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, dataset, ocr, handwriting-recognition

For handwriting recognition, the most common dataset is IAM but its used only for research purpose. Can anyone please suggest the handwritten word data set other than IAM for commercial usage.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the EMNIST Dataset?

Comment: EMNIST Datset is for individual characters. But I need the handwritten "word" images dataset with ground truth text.